# Execute a computing-intensive task in background

Tags: node.js

I have a task that requires a lot of computing without IO while executing and I don't want to block thread while executing this task. How can  I do this in `Node.js`?

I need something like this:

```
var taskManager = require("some-background-task-lib")

var doSomething = function() {
     // this code will calculate something and block thread
}

// this line should not block the Node.js event loop, but execute in background, then call the provided function when done
taskManager.executeInBackground(doSomething, function(err, returnValues) {
});
```

Comment: Start a child process.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to remove compute intensive stuff from blocking the main thread in node.js is to pass that work off to another process.  There are many ways to structure that.

1. Clustering where you have a group of processes all designed to execute the same thing and each one gets a different incoming request.
2. Create a specific child process designed specifically to execute a given task and create that child process that runs and then completes for the duration of the task whenever this particular task needs to be done.
3. Create a group of child processes and a queue of work and have each child process grab a work item from the queue, execute it, communicate back the result, then grab the next item from the queue, etc...

And, these techniques can be combined and one in combination too.

In the first case, you are just creating more processes all doing the same thing.

In the other two cases, you are specifically moving the compute intensive work to child processes so the main process is not burdened or blocked by that work.

There are a number of libraries that help provide an interface for using child processes.  One such library provides the [webWorker type of interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads).

Comment: Do you have any external links by any chance to any of the methods that describe in more detail how these things are accomplished? Very curious myself how these are done! By child processes i am thinking async calls to another express/etc server that computes the logic. Not sure if i am way off...@jfriend00

Comment: @MarkPieszak - The core child process library for node.js is here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html.  I already provided you a link (in my answer) to a webWorker interface library.  There are literally hundreds of modules written to solve problems like this.  Which to use depends upon the specifics of your situation which you have not shared.

Comment: Amazing thank you! I have plenty of reading ahead of me. I am not the OP just curious and been learning Node the past year more aggressively. Thanks friend!

Answer (score 0):

You need background workers and some kind of communication protocol between your web instance and worker instances. For example you can use [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) to create tasks queue

```
// web worker
var kue = require('kue');
var queue = kue.createQueue();

....

app.post('/calculateSomeCrazyStuff', (req, res, err) => {
  queue.create('myLongRunningJobName1', {
    fibonacciSequence: 52
  }).save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.status(204).send();
  });
});



// jobs worker
var kue = require('kue');
var queue = kue.createQueue();


queue.process('myLongRunningJobName1', function(job, done) {
  // calculate fibonacci
  done();
});
```